# What is the difference in behaviour/performance of these transmission line termination methods?

Tags: transmission-line, termination

The termination methods are:

1. Open-circuit or capacitive termination
2. Parallel resistive termination.
3. Thevenin termination.
4. Series termination at the source.
5. Parallel termination with voltage bias.
6. Parallel termination with series. capacitor.

I need top find out what is the difference between the behaviour of these and which to use when.

Comment: Terminating implies reduction of reflections so what have you determined so far? Do you understand what it means when a t-line reflects? Have you learnt that dc bias has no effect on reflections? Have you learnt that a capacitive termination will cause reflections at high frequencies? What is your target application and what are your expectations? Other than that this is too broad for this site's Q and A format.

Comment: Where did you get this list from? This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: I know about number 2 and 4 but did not know about the others' existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior or the transmission line structure can generally be found by using the input impedance formula for most of the types of terminations you listed above. For a load impedance, \$Z_L\$,This formula is:
$$
Z_{in} = Z_0\frac{Z_L + jZ_0 \tan(\beta l) }{Z_0 + jZ_L \tan(\beta l)}
$$

From this equivalent input (load) impedance \$Z_{in}\$ you can determine the behavior of the termination in terms of the voltage or current waves as follows. First you must determine the voltage reflection coefficient \$\Gamma\$:
$$
\Gamma = \frac{Z_{in} - Z_0}{Z_{in} + Z_0}
$$
Then you can determine the voltage (or current) waveform on the transmission line since,

$$
V(z) = V_0\left(e^{-j\beta z}+\Gamma e^{j\beta z}\right)\\
I(z) = \frac{V_0}{Z_0}\left(e^{-j\beta z}-\Gamma e^{j\beta z}\right)
$$
so for the list of terminations you've generated you can pretty easily determine the behavior of the voltage and current on the line.

Open and short terminations have total reflection with maximum voltage or current, respectively, at the end of the line. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, this is not the place to explain everything related to transmission lines.

Have you read [this article in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflections_of_signals_on_conducting_lines) ?

*distance between the behaviour* That is impossible to answer as a transmission line will simply **not work properly** when it is not terminated properly.

Transmission lines are intended to transport high frequency signals without distorting/damaging the signals. This is only the case when a transmission line is terminated properly at both ends, input and output.

Without proper termination, signals will reflect resulting in distorted and damaged signals.

Comment: Sorry. It was supposed to be difference and not distance.

Comment: OK, but answer still valid :-)